# Prevent reflow/redraw every time @State is changed

Tags: swiftui, combine

`didSelectItemAt` causes UI to reflow/redraw every time value for `lastSelectedIndex` is changed, causing performance issue. I'm not sure if I have used `@State` properly to propagate value from child to parent.

P.S. I need to use UICollectionView for a reason instead of swiftui `List` or `ScrollView`.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var lastSelectedIndex : Int = -1
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            CustomCollectionView(lastSelectedIndex: $lastSelectedIndex)
            Text("Current Selected Index \(lastSelectedIndex)")
        }
    }
}

struct CustomCollectionView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var lastSelectedIndex : Int
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICollectionView {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 300)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        collectionView.register(CustomCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CustomCollectionViewCell.reuseId)
        collectionView.delegate = context.coordinator
        collectionView.dataSource = context.coordinator
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        collectionView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        return collectionView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UICollectionView, context: Context) {
        uiView.reloadData()
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> CustomCoordinator {
        CustomCoordinator(self)
    }
}

class CustomCoordinator: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    let parent:CustomCollectionView
    
    init(_ parent:CustomCollectionView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CustomCollectionViewCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cell.label.text = "Current Index is \(indexPath.row)"
        NSLog("Called for Index \(indexPath.row)")
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        parent.lastSelectedIndex = indexPath.row
    }
}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseId = "customCell"
    let label = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Quick fix

You can use an ObservableObject for this purpose

```swift
class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var index: Int
    init(index: Int) { self.index = index }
}
```

Create a container view for your text field that will update when this model changes:

```
struct IndexPreviewer: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: Model
    var body: Text { Text("Current Selected Index \(model.index)") }
}
```

Then include this model and the observer in your ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let model = Model(index: -1)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            IndexPreviewer(model: model)
            CustomCollectionView(lastSelectedIndex: index)
        }
    }
    var index: Binding<Int> {
        Binding {model.index} set: {model.index = $0}
    }
}
```

## Explanation

The problem is that once you update a `@State` property, the containing view's `body` will be re-evaluated. So you cannot create a @State property on the view that contains your collection view, because each time you select a different cell, a message will be sent to your container who will re-evaluate it's body that contains the collection view. Hence the collection view will refresh and reload your data like [Asperi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12299030) wrote in his answer.

So what can you do to resolve that? Remove the state property wrapper from your container view. Because when you update the `lastSelectedIndex`, your container view (`ContentView`) should not be rendered again. But your Text view should be updated. So you should wrap your Text view in a separate view that **observes** the selection index.
This is where ObservableObject comes in to play. It is a class that can store State data on itself instead of being stored directly in a property of a view.

So why does `IndexPreviewer` update when the model changes and `ContentView` not, you might ask? That is because of the `@ObservedObject` property wrapper. Adding this to a view will refresh the view when the associated ObservableObject changes. That is why we do **not** include `@ObservedObject` inside ContentView but we do include it in `IndexPreviewer`.

**How/Where to store your models?**

For the sake of simplicity I added the `model` as a constant property to `ContentView`. This is however not a good idea when ContentView is not the root view of your SwiftUI hierarchy.
Say for example that your content view also receives a `Bool` value from its parent:

```
struct Wrapper: View {
    @State var toggle = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("toggle", isOn: $toggle)
            ContentView(toggle: toggle)
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    let toggle: Bool
    private let model = Model(index: -1)
    ...
}
```

When you run that on iOS 13 or 14 and try to click on collection view cell and then change the toggle, you will see that the selected index will reset to -1 when you change the toggle. Why does this happen?

When you click on the toggle, the `@State var toggle` will change and since it uses the @State property wrapper the `body` of the view will be recomputed. So another `ContentView` will be constructed and with it, also a new `Model` object.

There are two ways to prevent this from happening. One way is to move your model up in the hierarchy. But this can create a cluttered root view at the top of your view hierarchy. In some cases it is better to leave transient UI state local to your containing UI component. This can be achieved by an undocumented trick which is to use `@State` for your model objects. Like I said, it is currently (july 2020) undocumented but properties wrapped using @State will persist their value accross UI updates.

So to make a long story short: You should probably be storing your model using:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var model = Model(index: -1)
```

Comment: Changed as suggested, but `updateUIView` is still called for change in `lastSelectedIndex` `https://gist.github.com/vjyanand/fe36cfbfc6158c559894dfd6a7becd8b`

Comment: OK, it didn't work indeed. Sorry for not testing. You will need a model class like this: https://gist.github.com/Dev1an/a79985b1052afcdc70517ca539ada858

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to incorporate the working code and an explanation

Comment: Does the error appear in Xcode 11 or 12? Because that is Swift 5.3 syntax for `Binding(get: {model.index} set: {model.index = $0})`

Comment: Works in Swift 5.3

Comment: Greetings @DamiaanDufaux, THANK YOU VERY VERY MUCH.

Answer (score 1):

It is a feature of `@State` to cause dependent view refresh. In case of representable changing dependent state calls `updateUIView`, so, as you put `reloadData` in it - its reloaded:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UICollectionView, context: Context) {
    // Either remove reload from here (ig. make it once in makeUIView to load
    // content, or make reload here only conditionally depending on some parameter
    // which really needs collection to be reloaded
    // uiView.reloadData()
}
```